# iam trying to integrate hubspot with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, integration, hubspot

i got this code from github,  [laravel-hubspot](https://github.com/rossjcooper/laravel-hubspot) but by this code it was getting only firstname and lastname if i declare: `$contact->properties->email->value;` email or phonenumber or any other values from hubspot contacts it was not getting.
And all i need is how to get all the contact fields details from the hubspot contact

```php
$response = $hubspot->contacts()->all();
foreach ($response->contacts as $contact) {
    echo sprintf(
        "Contact name is %s %s." . PHP_EOL,
        $contact->properties->firstname->value,
        $contact->properties->lastname->value
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$contacts = Hubspot::contacts()->all([
        'property'  => ['firstname', 'lastname', 'hs_lead_status', 'email']
    ]);
    dd($contacts);
```

Comment: please explain your answer